# Authentication for a reactjs application using two private routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My reactjs application has two types of Users namely Artist and Lovers. Some of my components are only accessible to artist and some are only accessible to lovers. So i need to implement Artist and User Routes that will help grand access only to the required User type.
And here is my Router Switch

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <UserRoute authed={this.state.lover} path='/user-dash' component={About} />
    <ArtistRoute authed={this.state.artist} path='/artist-dash' component={Contact} />
    <Route path='/SignupUser' component={SignupUser} />
</Switch>
```

Here is my UserRoute code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
export const UserRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        authed
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
   )} />
)
```

I want to be able to receive the value of authed in the UserRoute passed in the switch. I do not know why authed in the UserRoute always returns false. 
even when this.state.lover passed to it is true. Please what am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: You should use a HOC

Comment: @RaajNadar any directives on it?? or link

Comment: @RaajNadar am using redux

Answer (score 0):

Route.jsx

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/user-dash' component={AuthCheck(About)} /> // Wrap the component with HOC
</Switch>
```

AuthCheck.jsx

```
export default function(Component) {
    class AuthCheck extends Component {
        render() {
            if (this.props.auth.payload) {
                return <Component {...this.props} /> // Component if auth is true
            } else {
                return <Route path='*' exact={true} component={NotFound} /> // 404 if not auth
            }
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return { auth: state.auth }
    }

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthCheck)
}
```

Check the above example works with redux

Make sure to import `AuthCheck` in the Route.jsx file